# What is the quickest way to find in which plots a set of points lie?

Tags: spatialite, optimization

I know this sounds easy and lazy to ask, but I'm new to (spatial)database, and I have the feeling my solution is sub-optimal. But for my situation it's important to have good performance.

## What do I have now:

- Python 3.4 @ Win7-64,
- SQLite v3.8.11.1 with Spatialite v4.3.0 via APSW
- Two tables; Plots (up to 1m rows) and Points (100 to 200 rows). In real life the points lie on a (almost) straight line.
- The position of the points in update constantly, and after each update I need to find out in which plot the points are.
- A View containing all plots inside the MBR of the points-table. The view is made by use of a SpatialIndex.

  ```
  CREATE VIEW 'View' AS SELECT * FROM Plots, idx_Points_geom  
  WHERE idx_Plots_geom.xmax > (SELECT MIN(xmin) FROM idx_Points_geom) 
  AND   idx_Plots_geom.xmin < (SELECT MAX(xmax) FROM idx_Points_geom) 
  AND   idx_Plots_geom.ymax > (SELECT MIN(ymin) FROM idx_Points_geom) 
  AND   idx_Plots_geom.ymin < (SELECT MAX(ymax) FROM idx_Points_geom) 
  AND   idx_Plots_geom.pkid == Plots.id
  ```
- The following query, giving me for each point the corresponding plot.

  ```
  SELECT * FROM "Points", "View"  
  WHERE Within("Points"."geom", "view"."geom")
  ```

## What did I do already:

I reduced the size of the view, by making it from the MBR of subgroups of points (i.e. 1-50, 51-100, 101-150). This reduced the size of the view dramatically, and speeds up the whole process.

## What do I want:

A general question I have is: Am I using the right approach to get plots in which the points are? Especially because I know the points are on a line and have a known distance between them.

And more specific: I believer my query is inefficient. Because I know each point is in only one plot, I would like the 'Within-function' to continue to evaluating the next point as soon a it finds the first point-plot match. This could reduce the number of test by 50%.
How do I enforce this? Putting a 'LIMIT 1' at the end of the query will only result in the answer for one point.

Comment: Are your plot geometries complex with lots of vertices or are they rather quite simple?

Comment: This should be good reading for you http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA1/WorldBorders.pdf. Your usage of spatial index is not very effective because it only cut out plots which are outside the total BBOX of all your points. You noticed the effect when you made sub-groups but it is not enough, you must read the spatial index separately for each point. The SQL will look pretty different.

Comment: You aren't applying the spatial index. Show some real data, and we can look at a better solution. Also, you might want to quantify what "constantly" means in terms of your point updates.

Comment: @user30184 The plots already are simple squares. I have thought to merge them into bigger ones, but now I understand that's not a good idea. How do I use the spatial index on the view as well? I gave it some tries, but I didn't get any improvements.